# How to send data from React to Flask then back to react and show output on DOM

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, api, flask

Im trying to pass data from React --> Flask --> React and show it in the DOM.

So far I been able to:

- Send data from React to Flask and display the output on the console. (POST)
- Send data from flask to React and display it on the DOM (GET)

So now my confusion is how do I put these 2 together. Here is my React code to send my data to Flask Username.js (POST)

```
##REACT
class Content extends Component {
 login = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios
            .post("/username", {
                username: document.getElementById("username").value,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log( res.data);
            });
    };

    

  render() {
    return(

      <div className="p"> <User />

      <form onSubmit={this.login}>
                        <p>
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <input
                                type="username"
                                className="w3-input w3-border"
                                id="username"
                            />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <button type="submit" className="w3-button w3-blue">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                   
              </div>      

        
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how I receive my data on flask

```
###FLASK
@app.route("/username", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.json["username"]
    #username = request.args.get('username')
    return {"username": 'This is the backend -- >'+ username }
```

When adding anything on my input label I can see it on the console. Now what I want is to get the result that I added on the input in the DOM. This can be on another page maybe?

Do I need to create a new route and pass the data from the /username? and then make an API call on my react app to this new route? How can I pass this username output to another route?  Is this the right way of doing it?

Please advice thank you

Answer (score 3):

from your front-end code it seems that you are sending a post request of type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, that it's the default request for html5 form.
In your backend logic you're tring to get incoming data as json with the following code `request.json["username"]`. Instead you should use `request.form["username"]` or `request.form.get("username", "")`.

Here a little resume:

- `request.args`: the key/value pairs in the URL query string
- `request.form`: the key/value pairs in the body, from a HTML post form,
  or JavaScript request that isn't JSON encoded request.files: the
  files in the body, which Flask keeps separate from form. HTML forms
  must use enctype=multipart/form-data or files will not be uploaded.
- `request.values`: combined args and form, preferring args if keys
  overlap request.json: parsed JSON data. The request must have the
  application/json content type, or use request.get_json(force=True) to
  ignore the content type.
- `request.files`: the files in the body, which Flask keeps separate from form. HTML
  forms
  must use enctype=multipart/form-data or files will not be uploaded.
- `request.values`: combined args and form, preferring args if keys overlap
- `request.json`: parsed JSON data. The request must have the application/json
  content type, or use request.get_json(force=True) to ignore the content type.

Your input field in front-end code should look like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.login} method="post">
    <p>
       <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
       <input type="username" className="w3-input w3-border" id="username" name="username" />
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="submit" className="w3-button w3-blue" value="Login" />
   </p>
</form>
```

Changes added :

- `method="post"` : default method in html 5 form is GET
- `name="username"` : as new attribute for input
- `input type="submit"` : instead of button

Your back-end should be like this:

```
@app.route("/username", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form.get("username", "") # or request.form["username"]
    return jsonify(username=username) # from flask import jsonify
```

I advice you to use jsonify() to return json data.

Finally in your front-end code if you want to print json response with the collected username should update your code in something like this:

```
.post("/username", {
      username: document.getElementById("username").value,
})
.then((res) => {
     // JSON response is handled by a json() promises
     return res.json().then( (data) => console.log(data));
});
```

Comment: I got it! Is there a way of sending the form data back to React without storing it on a database? OR I need to include a DB where I save the react form data so I can send it back to React?

Comment: You can include your form data in the json response with other datas. One other option if we are talking about of no sensitive data such as passwords, could be save this data on localstorage or index DB.